# Using connectorx to load data from mysql db changes datatype of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am using *connectorx* to read data from MySQL database into a pandas dataframe. The date and text type columns of dataframe now look like **b''** and this is creating problems for urther calculations. My code and output is mentioned below with dummy data.

```
import connectorx as cx
db_url="mysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost:{port}/{db}".format(user="testuser",pw="testpassword",db="cachedb",port=13306)
query="""Select * from test"""
df=cx.read_sql(db_url,query)

df1.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 150 entries, 0 to 149
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------        --------------  -----  
 0   sepal_length  150 non-null    float64
 1   sepal_width   150 non-null    float64
 2   petal_length  150 non-null    float64
 3   petal_width   150 non-null    float64
 4   species       150 non-null    object 
 5   species_id    150 non-null    Int64  
dtypes: Int64(1), float64(4), object(1)
memory usage: 7.3+ KB

df
```

[image: Dataframe output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to decode byte strings as regular strings:

```
df['species'] = df['species'].str.decode('utf-8')  # or 'ascii'
print(df)

# Output
    species
0    setosa
1  virginia
```

Input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'species': [b'setosa', b'virginia']})
print(df)

# Output
       species
0    b'setosa'
1  b'virginia'
```